# Free IDE + assembler + software emulator for x86 (MASM) assembly?

Tags: x86, emulation, assembly

I'm currently trying to get into x86 assembly ( I already have some pre-existing knowledge with x51 assembly) and I'm looking for a simple IDE+assembler+emulator for the assembly output.

Can you recommend any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend the [Flat Assembler](http://flatassembler.net/index.php). Comes with a pretty nice and tiny IDE, runs on Windows, Linux, and MS-DOS.

There's also the [Netwide Assembler](http://nasm.us), which comes with a disassembler, but no IDE. Altough FASM's simple IDE is easily reproduced with any editor that allows for external commands.

Comment: Is it possible to set the Flat Assembler as the default program for opening .asm files?

Answer (score 1):

[Masm32](http://www.masm32.com/) comes with a text editor that works well.  Not a full-blown IDE, but a full IDE is not of as much use for Asm as it is for higher level languages anyways.  It's licensed, but is licensed as freeware.  I've used a number of different assemblers over the years and have never encountered one that I truly didn't like.  However, Masm32 is my current favorite.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) with [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs).

There are simpler IDEs, but I do all other development in VS so I'm already familiar with it.

Why NASM over MASM? Better cross-platform compatibility in case I decide to compile for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[SASM](https://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html) is a simple cross-platform IDE that is good for learning.